# What is the best way to collect money from friend who owes me some money

Tags: law, debt-collection

I have this person who tries to run away from me and not paying me back as he promised. Since this is not my area and never involved something like this,  don't know what to do. Please advise me some options, shall I use a debt collector or law professionals or something else. What probably the most difficult part is I do not know his home address. He does not respond to my emails and SNS messages. I need somebody can reach him and pass my message or collect money from him. What I can give as his info are his company info which he runs, his cell number and his Facebook. Thank you for your time and helpful comments in advance.

Comment: Why would you lend money to someone you barely know?

Comment: This person is not your friend. He barely sounds like an acquaintance. Be prepared to prove you actually lent him the money.

Comment: How long have you known this friend? Have you ever met him in person? Do you have a physical address for the business he runs? Are you sure he really runs it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had such a case about 10 years ago with an acquiantance. Things started out small and grew a bit into 700-800€ until this guy stopped being responsive. In the end I just gave up as he was not living in my area and not responsive to anything. With things creeping up, I also did not have anything in writing, so involving debt collectors or a lawyer was not very promising. While it hurts losing that money, it was not worth to throw additional money after it and I booking this as a learning expense. Sometimes people learn best through pain.

So answer the following questions for your debt problem:

- Do you have anything written?
- Is it a sum you can afford to lose?
- Can you come by in person?

If you do not have anything written and you can afford to lose it, that's it. Maybe drop by personally but any legal action will likely not be successful. If you have anything written and cannot afford to lose that sum, involve a lawyer or debt collector.

Comment: @Lilly1022 Can you clarify your relation with this person by [edit]ing the question? You say "_who tries to run away from me_" which (to me) suggests that as you approach him _in person_ he turns around and loses himself in the crowd. However, in the above comment, you imply that you and he live in different countries (him in the USA, you somewhere else). Have you _actually met_ this person, or is it just an internet thing? If the latter, it's very possible the whole thing is a scam, and even the little you think you know about him may be false.